# Apex Error message: Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: trigger

I've created a trigger to populate **Field 1** on **Object 1** with **Field 2** from **Object 2** - when Field 2 is being created.
But I am having troubles saving it. I am getting an error message:

> "Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '<'. at line 10 column 6 ".

I am new to Apex, so I am not sure what I am missing, so a bit of help would be appreciated.

*I have created a lookup relationship between the 2 objects.

Please see below the trigger:

```
trigger updatefield1 on Object_2__c (before insert, before update){

    List<Object_1__C> Obj1IDs = new List<Object_1__C>();

    for(Object_2__c obj: trigger.new){
        Obj1IDs.add(Ite.Object_1__c);
    }
    List <Object_1__c> obj1s = new List <Object_1__c> ([select id, field_1__c from Object_1__c, where id in: Obj1IDs]); - //this is line 10 - where the error is

    for (Object_2__c obj: trigger.new){
        for  (integer i=0; i < obj1s.size(); i++){

            if (obj.Object_1__c == obj1s[i].id{
                obj1s[i].field_1__c = field_2__c;
            }
        }
    }
    update obj1s;
}
```

Comment: Syntax error i.e. additional comma after `Object_1__c`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've managed to get rid of that error message, but now I am getting a new one "Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist:" on line "Obj1IDs.add(Ite.Object_1__c);". I have added "Ite" to the code, but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas, @VijayGanji? Thanks.

Comment: Where have you declared "Ite" in this code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma after the object name in the SOQL. remove that `from Object_1__c,`

```
List <Object_1__c> obj1s = new List <Object_1__c> ([select id, field_1__c from Object_1__c where id in: Obj1IDs]);
```

- //this is line 10 - where the error is

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've managed to get rid of that error message, but now I am getting a new one "Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist:" on line "Obj1IDs.add(Ite.Object_1__c);". I have added "Ite" to the code, but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @SSimion it should be "obj", not "Ite" (since "obj" is the variable defined in your "for" loop scope). :)

Answer (score 0):

Close this if condition.

`if (obj.Object_1__c == obj1s[i].id)
{
    obj1s[i].field_1__c = field_2__c;
}`